# Is there a way of using a completion handler passed through as an argument to detect when a long request is completed

Tags: swift, closures

I'm having trouble understanding how to use a closure to handle completed events when passing in a function as a parameter.

Here's a very contrived example:

```
class MessageService {
    func sendMessage(s: String) {
        print(s)
    }
    
    var messenger: Messenger {
        createMessenger(completion: sendMessage(s:))
    }
}

func createMessenger(completion: @escaping (String) -> Void) -> Messenger {
    return Messenger { completion("This is a hardcoded message.") }
}

struct Messenger {
    let sendMessage: () -> Void
    init(sendMessage: @escaping () -> Void) {
        self.sendMessage = sendMessage
    }
}

let service = MessageService()
let messenger = service.messenger
messenger.sendMessage()
```

I want to find out when `sendMessage` is finished (if for example it was performing something like a network request), so is there a way of having a completion handler for `sendMessage` so that I could write something along the lines of:

```
messenger.sendMessage {
    print("I finished sending a message!")
}
```

I've tried adding a completion handler like this in the service class:

```
func sendMessage(s: String, completion: @escaping () -> Void) {
    MessageRequest(with: s) {
        completion()
    }
}
```

But things started getting very confusing when I'm trying to use the `createMessenger` method, because the above function has some crazy type of `(String, () -> ()) -> ()` which I don't know how to handle. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: not directly related comment, but I find it very difficult to keep track of all the "something"s that you have there. Can you update your question and give either more descriptive or just different names where it makes sense

Comment: Sure I'll try make something more readable :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, it sounds like what you want is an arbitrary Messenger type, whose creator tell it what action to do, and once the action is done, it invokes its caller's completion handler.

It helps if you use `typealias` with descriptive names to keep track of all the closures. And if you don't mind, I'll name it more generically as `Agent`:

```
struct Agent {

   typealias Completion = () -> Void
   typealias Action = (Completion) -> Void

   private let action: Action

   static func create(action: @escaping Action) -> Agent {
      Agent(action: action)
   }

   func execute(_ completion: @escaping Completion) {
      action(completion)
   }
}
```

So, `Agent` can be created with an arbitrary action that accepts a completion handler to signal when it's done:

```
let agent = Agent.create { completion in
   print("started executing action")
   DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2) { completion() }
}
```

```
agent.execute { print("done") }
```

Now, you can adapt it to your `MessengerService` class:

```
class MessageService {
   func sendMessage(s: String) {
      print(s)
   }
    
   var messenger: Agent {
      Agent.create { completion in 
         sendMessage("This is a hardcoded message.") 
         completion()
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer, it's a great solution and actually very elegant. p.s. good call for renaming it to `Agent`, it makes it much clearer for anyone else looking :)